# sails-postgresql "ReferenceError: User is not defined"

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sails.js, waterline, sails-postgresql

I try to set up postgresql connection with sails.js . Here is my config:

api/models/User.js:

```
module.exports = {

tableName: 'user',
meta: {
    schemaName: 'public'
},
identity:'sails',
connection: 'postgreSQL',

attributes: {
username:{
    type:'string',
    required:true,
},
password:{
    type:'string',
    required:true,
},
email:{
    type:'email',
    required:true,
},
}};
```

config/connections.js:

```
module.exports.connections = {
postgreSQL: {
      adapter: 'sails-postgresql',
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      user: 'sails', // optional
      password: 'pass', // optional
      database: 'sails', //optional
      port:5433,
    }
}
```

config/models.js

```
module.exports.models = {
  connection: 'postgreSQL',
  migrate: 'safe',    
};
```

api/controllers/UserController.js

```
module.exports = {
    create: function(req,res){
        User.create(req.allParams()).exec(function createdUser(err, created){
            if(created != undefined){
                sails.log('Utilisateur créé')
                res.view('User/user_created');
                sails.log(req.allParams())
            }
            else
            {
                sails.log('Pas d\'utilisateur créé')
                sails.log(req.allParams())
            }

        });
    },

    search: function(req,res){
    sails.log("Recherche saisie:")
    sails.log(req.allParams())
    if(req.allParams() == undefined){
        sails.log("Pas d'utilisateur recherché");
    }
    else {
        User.find({username : {contains: req.allParams().username}}).exec(function (err, userFound){
        sails.log('utilisateur trouvé');
        sails.log(userFound);
        return res.json(userFound);
    })
    }
    }
};
```

When I lift my app, and i send the following request (which send post agument as params for "create" action from UserController):

http://127.0.0.1:1337/User/Subscribe?username=pierre&password=pass&email=test@test.fr

I have the error:

> error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response:  ReferenceError: User is
>   not defined
>       at Object.create (C:\Users\Pierre\Documents\Geek\SAILS\hikout\api\controllers\UserController.js:10:3)
>       at wrapper (C:\Users\Pierre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\@sailshq\lodash\lib\index.js:3250:19)
>       at routeTargetFnWrapper (C:\Users\Pierre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\lib\router\bind.js:181:5)
>       at callbacks (C:\Users\Pierre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:164:37)
>       at param (C:\Users\Pierre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:138:11)
>       at pass (C:\Users\Pierre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:145:5)
>       at nextRoute (C:\Users\Pierre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:100:7)
>       at callbacks (C:\Users\Pierre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:167:11)
>       at alwaysAllow (C:\Users\Pierre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\lib\hooks\policies\index.js:224:11)
>       at routeTargetFnWrapper (C:\Users\Pierre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\lib\router\bind.js:181:5)
>       at callbacks (C:\Users\Pierre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:164:37)
>       at param (C:\Users\Pierre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:138:11)
>       at pass (C:\Users\Pierre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:145:5)
>       at nextRoute (C:\Users\Pierre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:100:7)
>       at callbacks (C:\Users\Pierre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:167:11)
>       at module.exports (C:\Users\Pierre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\lib\hooks\cors\clear-headers.js:14:3)
>       at routeTargetFnWrapper (C:\Users\Pierre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\lib\router\bind.js:181:5)
>       at callbacks (C:\Users\Pierre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:164:37)
>       at param (C:\Users\Pierre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:138:11)
>       at pass (C:\Users\Pierre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:145:5)
>       at nextRoute (C:\Users\Pierre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:100:7)
>       at callbacks (C:\Users\Pierre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\@sailshq\express\lib\router\index.js:167:11)

However all works perfectly without postgresSQL connection...  Does someone know how to solve this ?

Thank you in advance for help.

EDIT: I changed the files path to get the good ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the file paths were wrong in my first post. I had set up the right ones in my app.

The problem was in the file `config/models.js`. I was trying to run my app with the `safe` mode for my connection. However, this doesn’t work during the first run. The good way is to use either the `alter` or `drop` mode for your connection in order to create tables corresponding to your models during the first run.

The good `config/models.js` file is:

```js
module.exports.models = {
    connection: 'postgreSQL',
    migrate: 'alter',  // you can also use 'drop' 
};
```

I also had to change my model to look like so:

```js
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        username: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
        },
        email: {
            type:'string',
            required:true,
        },
        password: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
        },
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the model file for your User table.

It should be in `api/models/User.js`

I think you just need to move the file `api/controllers/User.js` to make it work.

Also renamed your `api/controller` folder to be `api/controllers`

Sails is convention based, if you put things in the right place it will work without fuss. So your model files need to go in

`api/models/TABLENAME.js
api/controllers/TABLENAMEController.js`

If both of these files are present, it will create the table and declare  global variable TABLENAME for you.